# Is there a way to create an sjcl.js bignum (bn) from an integer string?

Tags: bignum, sjcl

sjcl.js provides codecs for reading in hex strings and utf8Strings, but it doesn't provide a codec for reading in base-10 integer strings. I'm trying to read in private keys for ECC point generation that are from another program (going from codec to bitArray then from bitArray to bn). Seems like an odd oversight which leads me to believe it is in there somewhere, just missing it.

Thanks,

PeterT